# Function continues running even after set to undefined

Tags: javascript

I've written a wrapped around an API service, which creates a special function, `next`, which calls itself with the next page of data. It allows me to do stuff like:

```
let req = getSomeData({ param: true }, function(err, res) {
    // Do something
    if (res.next) {
        res.next();
    } else {
        // All data processed
    }
})
```

If I want to stop this automatic pagination early, I assumed I could just set `req = null`, and it would stop it running again, however the callback function continues to be run.

A minimalistic example is below:

```
var parent = function() {

  var runner = function(func) {
    var next = function() {
      return runner(func);
    }

    func(next)
  }

  var handler = function(next) {
    console.log('handler called')
    setTimeout(next, 2000);
  }

  runner(handler);
}

var child = new parent();

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('killing child');
  child = undefined;
  console.log('child is ' + typeof child);
}, 5000)
```

Even though after 5 seconds `child = undefined`, the handler function continues to be called every two seconds.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/tuyebacavi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: You need to call `clearTimeout()`. Simply de-referencing the object that initiated `setTimeout()` won't do

Comment: well.... based on your code, you unconditionally do setTimeout for the next iteration every 2 seconds.

Comment: This example with `setTimeout` is just a demo, the timeout was just added to pause it so it doesn't spam with logs. The real version does some data processing and external requests, which takes a few seconds, then calls `next`.

Comment: So? We have no clue how your actual code works. You'd have to implement some mechanism in your code to stop calling `next`, just setting some "random" reference to null won't do anything. With your current problem, you might want to look up how closures work in JS and especially related to memory-leaks due to closures and how to solve them (although it's not the same topic, but it's related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `stop` function make it more sensible :

```js
var parent = function() {
  var keepRunning = true;
  
  var runner = function(func) {
    var next = function() {
      return runner(func);
    }
    if(keepRunning)
      func(next)
  }
  
  var handler = function(next) {
    console.log('handler called')
    setTimeout(next, 2000);
  }
  
  this.stop = function(){
    keepRunning = false
  }
  
  runner(handler);
}

var child = new parent();

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('killing child');
  child.stop()
  console.log('child is ' + typeof child);
}, 5000)
```